# Can I compress SMS content to free up storage?

Tags: iphone, sms, storage, compression

My SMS on my iPhone is growing everyday. According to my iPhone's Usage function, I have about 1.2GB of SMS data. My phone has been running on low storage and any megabytes are precious.

Is there anyway to compress my SMS data or archive them to free up space on my phone? Although I don't refer to my old SMS messages all the time, I would still want to be able to search for them when I need. Perhaps this could be done either on my phone or on a computer or even over the cloud.

Otherwise, how do you usually manage your SMS data to keep them within reasonable storage space?

Answer (score 1):

The app [iExplorer](https://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/) can export one, several, or all messages from your iPhone and save them in a number of ways. Once you have exported and archived the conversations onto your Mac or PC, you can delete them from your phone & reclaim space.

[image]

The easiest takes each conversation and exports PDFs out of them with images attached in-line:

[image]

Other options let you save images & other attachments in a variety of ways:

[image]

Lowest price point is US$35, and well worth it.

[Full Disclosure: I'm just a happy customer who has no financial stake in Macroplant.]